# How to visualize differential forms geometrically

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition, differential-forms

I've been attempting to teach myself differential geometry and I have heard that one can visualise them geometrically and that this can sometimes be helpful for an intuitive understanding of them. For example, I've heard that one can visualise a one-form in 3-d as a collection of surfaces and that when one integrates such a one-form over a path it can be thought of loosely as counting the number of these surfaces that this path "pierces" as one "moves" along it. What is the reasoning behind this? Why can one (at least heuristically) think of differential forms in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that interpretation does make some sense. At a point, the one form is of course a dual vector, which annihilates tangent vectors in every direction but one. The directions it annihilates are tangent to the surface, while the direction it does not is normal to the surface. This means the form is not concerned about movements along the surfaces, but only perpendicular to them. The magnitude of the form can be thought of (strictly heuristically) as being how densely packed the surfaces are.

When you integrate a path, you can break down its movement into movement along the surfaces, which the one-form annihilates so it doesn't contribute to the value, and movement normal to the surfaces, which does contribute according to how densely the surfaces are packed, and so the heuristic interpretation of the integral also holds a sort of sense.

Comment: Ah OK, so the surface idea simply comes from the fact that a one-form, for example $dx$ "picks out" only the vector component perpendicular to the surface of constant $x$, i.e. $dx(\mathbf{v})=v_{x}$?

Comment: Yes, for differentials of a function, the surfaces are the level surfaces of the function.

Comment: *"the surfaces are the level surfaces of the function"* - how does one prove this?

Comment: Since we haven't even bothered to exactly define these surfaces (and I am not going to - this was supposed to be a heuristic concept), "proving" is a little hard, but: $V$ points along a surface for $df \equiv df(V) = 0 \equiv V(f) = 0 \equiv V$ points in a direction that $f$ does not vary $\equiv V$ is tangent to a level surface of $f$.

Comment: is it simply from noting that $df=\nabla f\cdot d\mathbf{x}$ and so if $df=0$ then it defines a level surface of constant $f$? ... Sorry, I posted this without refreshing the page so hadn't realised that  you'd already written a response :-\

Comment: Of course, this makes no sense when the 1-form isn't exact. ...

Comment: @TedShifrin - How so? Certainly the surfaces are not level surfaces of a function then, but the original heuristic concept is based on local behavior, and therefore does not care if the 1-form can be integrated.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Local behavior is still integrating. You only have the hyperplanes annihilated by the 1-form, but no (even germs) of surfaces.

Comment: @TedShifrin - Even if that were true, it would be enough for this heuristic picture. (I don't think it is true, but I don't have time right now to validate one part of my argument.)

Comment: @TedShifrin = the thing that struck immediately as wrong with your comment is that the entire raison d'etre of the tangent space is to serve as a linearized approximation to the manifold. But your comment would have hyperplanes corresponding to nothing. A basis can be found for $T_pM$ with the 1-form carrying all but one basis vector to 0. This basis corresponds to a local coordinate patch at $p$. The level surfaces of the coordinate function for the unannihilated vector are the surfaces in question. Inexactness merely means this coordinate function cannot be extended globally.

Comment: No, @PaulSinclair, you have a big misunderstanding here. There is no such coordinate function, even locally. Local to global is a question of cohomology, admittedly. To be concrete: Take $\omega = dz-y\,dx$ and give me surfaces on any open set you wish.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I'll agree that there is a misunderstanding here, but it is your demanding that an intuitive concept has to be strictly based on exact interpretation to have meaning. Since you didn't specify the point, I choose the origin $\omega(\partial_x) = 0, \omega(\partial_y) = 0, \omega(\partial_z) = 1$. The coordinate patch is the canonical coordinates, the coordinate function is $z$ The surfaces are the horizontal planes. That is all the justification this needs for its purpose. (I admit my last sentence in the previous comment was incorrect, though.)

Comment: @Paul: I'm very willing to be intuitive and taught in such a fashion for 40 years, but I want to be careful about saying blatantly wrong things. Your surfaces don't work locally near the origin; they only work along the hyperplane $y=0$.

Comment: And again, they don't need to. It has been *very clearly stated* that is a *heuristic picture only*. It doesn't need actual surfaces extending in neighborhoods around the point for the concept to have meaning. It is enough that its "surfaces" exist only in that linearized approximation of the manifold called the tangent space. For you to claim it makes no sense at all when the 1-form is not exact is completely missing the point of the concept. It's like dismissing differentials as senseless in the 1800s. Even Berkeley knew that they were useful, despite the complete lack of rigor then.